# Gitlab: gem not found

Tags: heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to deploy our app to `Heroku` and our settings in `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like

```
staging_heroku:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - git remote add heroku https://heroku:$STAGING_HEROKU_KEY@git.heroku.com/staging-myapp.git
  - git push -f heroku master
```

This is what we see in logs

```
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/org/project'...
Checking out 340111af as dev/feature1...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts for maven-build (17234382)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=17234382 responseStatus=200 OK token=2YSHdANA
/bin/sh: eval: line 46: apt-get: not found
$ apt-get update -yqqq
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

These runners do not even have `apt-get` and so I can not install `gem`.

I even tried `git` command, but even that is not found. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install `ruby` and `ruby-dev` first! (and `rubygems-integration` for Debian 8)

```
staging:
  type: deploy
  script:
  - apt-get update -yq
  - apt-get install -y ruby ruby-dev rubygems-integration
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=teeth-taroko --api-key=$HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY
  only:
  - develop
```